# Disable a pipeline during package/update installation wizard

Tags: pipelines

Is there any way to disable a specific pipeline, or part of a pipeline, during an item install via package or update installation wizard? I have a custom pipeline for item:created that I'd like to skip if it's not invoked via a standard item creation.

Comment: If you by "standard item creation" mean "Created in the Content Editor", you should hook into the uiSaved pipeline instead of having an event handler

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought the package installer disabled the events from firing. This isn't an answer, but take a look at this link:  http://www.delphicdigital.com/blog/how-to-write-a-custom-sitecore-disabler

Comment: Hmm, not sure, i was getting errors on item:created which is what made me think of this. I'm taking a page out of @MarkCassidy's suggestion and the branch presets, since I only need it when branch templates are created, and using addFromTemplate to do the trick. But Mark put me on the right path, so Mark if you want to frame as an answer I can give you the points, or I'll answer it myself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short; there isn't a way out of the box to disable events during package installation.

As an alternative, you can hook into a pipeline "closer to home" like `uiSaved` - this only triggers when an item is created in the Content Editor interface.

Might I add; item event handlers often trigger in situations never considered when they are first written. `item:created`, for example, also triggers the first time you publish a new item to "web". Be cautious of these :-)